# How to delete text using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import random

GAME_WIDTH = 700
GAME_HEIGHT = 700
SPEED = 75
SPACE_SIZE = 50
BODY_PARTS = 3
SNAKE_COLOR = "lime green"
BACKGROUND_COLOR = "black"

class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.body_size = BODY_PARTS
        self.coordinates = []
        self.squares = []

        for i in range(0, BODY_PARTS):
            self.coordinates.append([0, 0])

        for x, y in self.coordinates:
            square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR, tag="snake")
            self.squares.append(square)



class Food:
    def __init__(self):
        x = random.randint(0, (GAME_WIDTH/SPACE_SIZE)-1) * SPACE_SIZE
        y = random.randint(0, (GAME_HEIGHT/SPACE_SIZE)-1) * SPACE_SIZE

        self.coordintes = [x,y]

        canvas.create_oval(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill = "red", tag = "food")

def next_turn(snake, food):
    x, y = snake.coordinates[0]

    if direction == "up":
        y -= SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == "down":
        y += SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == "left":
        x -= SPACE_SIZE
    elif direction == "right":
        x += SPACE_SIZE

    snake.coordinates.insert(0, (x, y))

    square = canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=SNAKE_COLOR)
    snake.squares.insert(0, square)

    if x == food.coordintes[0] and y == food.coordintes[1]:
        global score
        score += 1
        label.config(text = "score: " + str(score))
        canvas.delete("food")
        food = Food()

    else:
        del snake.coordinates[-1]
        canvas.delete(snake.squares[-1])
        del snake.squares[-1]
    if check_collisions(snake):
        game_over()
    else:
        window.after(SPEED, next_turn, snake, food)

def change_direction(new_direction):
    global direction
    if new_direction == "left":
        if direction != "right":
            direction = new_direction
    elif new_direction == "right":
        if direction != "left":
            direction = new_direction
    elif new_direction == "up":
        if direction != "down":
            direction = new_direction
    elif new_direction == "down":
        if direction != "up":
            direction = new_direction


def check_collisions(snake):
    x, y = snake.coordinates[0]

    if x < 0 or x >= GAME_WIDTH:
        return True
    elif y < 0 or y >= GAME_HEIGHT:
        return True

    for body_part in snake.coordinates[1:]:
        if x == body_part[0] and y == body_part[1]:
            return True
    return False


def game_over():
    global text
    canvas.delete(ALL)
    text = canvas.create_text(canvas.winfo_width()/2, canvas.winfo_height()/2,
                       font = "Times 70 bold", text = "Game Over", fill = "red")
def play_again():
    global score
    score = 0
    label.config(text="score: " + str(score))
    BODY_PARTS = 3
    canvas = Canvas(window, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR, height=GAME_HEIGHT, width=GAME_WIDTH)
    canvas.pack()
    snake = Snake()
    food = Food()
    next_turn(snake, food)



window = Tk()
window.title("snake game")

score = 0
direction = "right"

label = Label(window,
              text = "Score: "+ str(score),
              font = "Times 40 bold",
              )
label.pack()

canvas = Canvas(window, bg = BACKGROUND_COLOR, height = GAME_HEIGHT, width = GAME_WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

window.update()

window_width = window.winfo_width()
window_height = window.winfo_height()
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()

x = int((screen_width/2) - (window_width/2))
y = int((screen_height/2) - (window_height/2))
window.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")

window.bind("<Left>", lambda event: change_direction("left"))
window.bind("<Right>", lambda event: change_direction("right"))
window.bind("<Up>", lambda event: change_direction("up"))
window.bind("<Down>", lambda event: change_direction("down"))
window.bind("<f>", lambda event: play_again(), canvas.delete("text"))


snake = Snake()
food = Food()

next_turn(snake, food)


window.mainloop()
```

I'm not sure how to remove the game over text and I'm not sure why canvas.delete("text")
doesn't remove it, what mistake am I making. Whenever I press the f key the game replays but the game over text remains
[image of the game over text remaining when the game replays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8TQi.png) above is the full code of the program

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre], and try to narrow the code example down to only the parts of the UI that are needed to demonstrate the problem. Please also try to ask a question more clearly. If you "aren't sure how to" do something, then show us what things you tried, explain exactly what went wrong with each of them, and explain the underlying logic for trying them. Please also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and look for potential causes of the problem.

Comment: hint: `lambda event: play_again(), canvas.delete("text")` isn't doing what you think. `canvas.delete("text")` is not part of the lambda, and is instead executing immediately.

Answer (score 3):

You are not deleting the canvas.text object, which you have put in the global variable `text`.  The expression:

```
canvas.delete("text")
```

deletes all of the objects in the canvas that have the tag "text".  There are no such objects, because you haven't used the tag feature; but that's not an error.  To delete the object represented by the global variable `text`, do this:

```
canvas.delete(text)
```

On top of that, you seem to be trying to bind two different functions to the "f" key at the same time.  The way to do that is like this:

```
window.bind("<f>", lambda event: play_again())
window.bind("<f>", lambda event: canvas.delete(text), add='+')
```

Also, your `play_again` function creates an entirely new canvas, but that object is bound to a local variable named `canvas` which will hide the global variable of the same name.  That is something you need to fix as well.